# How can I promote human rights petitions to the UN?

Tags: united-nations, human-rights, egypt

How can I promote petitions about corruption and human rights violations in Egypt to the UN Human Rights Council?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the [United Nations Human Rights Council]
(http://www.ohchr.org/EN/HRBodies/HRC/ComplaintProcedure/Pages/HRCComplaintProcedureIndex.aspx) vis their complaint form on the same page.

> **How does the complaint procedure work?**
>
> Pursuant to paragraph 94 of resolution 5/1, the Chairperson of the Working Group on Communications, together with the Secretariat, undertake an initial screening of communications based on the admissibility criteria set in paragraphs 85 to 88 of resolution 5/1. Manifestly ill-founded and anonymous communications are screened out. Communications not rejected in the initial screening are transmitted to the State concerned to obtain its views on the allegations of violations. Both the author of a communication and the State concerned are informed of the proceedings at each stage.

Comment: Ugh. Sounds like they transmit the origin of the claim to the state. Wonder how that works out for the typical claimant in a state with a record of actual rights abuses.

Comment: @DVK - There is nothing to see there.  Most claims are admittedly false and libelous lies about the great humanitarian leaders of the middle east, and southeast Asia.  They have agents that are skilled in getting to the truth behind these lies.